# Log4j2+Glassfish+NetBeans: How to get Automatic Reconfiguration working when edit and save log4j2.xml (when deployed in place)

Tags: logging, glassfish, log4j, log4j2

EDIT: Reported as: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1586

---

```
Log4j2: v2.5
Glassfish: v4.1
NetBeans IDE: 8.1beta
```

With a NetBeans web app deployed over the project's build folder (not as a separate deployed WAR).

From https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticReconfiguration:

> When configured from a File, Log4j has the ability to automatically
>   detect changes to the configuration file and reconfigure itself. If
>   the monitorInterval attribute is specified on the configuration
>   element and is set to a non-zero value then the file will be checked
>   the next time a log event is evaluated and/or logged and the
>   monitorInterval has elapsed since the last check. The example below
>   shows how to configure the attribute so that the configuration file
>   will be checked for changes only after at least 30 seconds have
>   elapsed. The minimum interval is 5 seconds.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
...
</Configuration>
```

But when I edit and save the /build/web/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml nothing happens, the Automatic Reconfiguration magic fails. The log4j2.xml is otherwise found and seems to work fine.

Comment: I also use Log4j2 at the server level, and for that configuration file/context, the status log says `DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/home/[...]`, pointing to the actual XML file. And indeed, the automatic reconfiguration does work on that level.

Comment: @HeinBlöd With `<Configuration status="ALL" monitorInterval="5">` and the webapp deployed directly from NetBeans8.1 into Glassfish4.1.1 (over the .../build) I get: `admin-listener(2) DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/.../webapp/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml] initialized`. Editing the log levels in that log4j2.xml file does not get caught.

Answer (score 1):

Answering self: This answers the initial question/problem:

*How to get Automatic Reconfiguration working when edit and save log4j2.xml (when deploying in place to Glassfish from NetBeans)*

**But is only a workaround**, as it does not explain why the documented technique `<Configuration monitorInterval="5">` does not work, so other answers are still welcome.

There is no problem when I use this system parameter in the project Run VM args:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/Users/.../webapp/build/web/WEB-IN‌​F/classes/log4j2.xml‌​
```

I can then clearly see the file change being caught and reconfiguration happening in the glassfish log:

```
Info:   2016-09-16 10:47:24,669 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-2 INFO File  /Users/.../webapp/build/web/WEB-IN‌​F/classes/log4j2.xml‌​ was modified
Info:   2016-09-16 10:47:24,670 Log4j2-1 DEBUG Reconfiguration started for context  
....
```

And the changes made to log levels by editing that file are then caught.